# Adding a KML file into a GeoDjango field

Tags: django, kml, geodjango

I'm trying to add a KML file to a field in GeoDjango.  [Link to KML file](https://github.com/Valachio/bungol/blob/master/AjaxResponse.aspx).  I tried to follow the answer [on this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140634/import-kml-file-into-geodjango) but it's mostly wrong.

My model:

```
class School(models.Model):
    boundaries = models.PolygonField(null=True)
```

---

```
i = School.objects.get(...)
ds = DataSource('school.aspx')
layer = ds[0]   #The file only has 1 layer
geom = layer.get_geoms()
boundary = GEOSGeometry(geom[0])
i.boundaries = boundary
i.save()
```

The above code gives me the following error:

`TypeError: Improper geometry input type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.gdal.geometries.Polygon'>`

---

When I try to add the field directly, like this:

```
i = School.objects.get(...)
ds = DataSource('school.aspx')
layer = ds[0]
geom = layer.get_geoms()
i.boundaries = geom[0]
i.save()
```

I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot set School SpatialProxy (POLYGON) with value of type: <class 'django.contrib.gis.gdal.geometries.Polygon'>`

How do I save the polygon shape in the KML file into my database?  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `.geos` property of gdal geoms:

```
ds = DataSource('school.kml')
o = School(boundaries=ds[0][0].geom.geos)
o.save()
```